# Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI must not be null when using RestAssured in SpringBootTest aginst the RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, rest-assured

This the `BaseTest` abstract class where the configuration is being set :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class BaseIntegration {

@Value("${local.server.port}")
private int serverPort;

@Before
public void setup() {
    RestAssured.port = serverPort;
}}
```

The test class is very simple :

```
public class TestIT extends BaseIntegration{//Test Code}
```

`RestClient` created using `RestAssured` :

```
public static TestResponse postResponse(TestRequest request) {

    return given().log().all()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(request)
            .when()
            .log().all()
            .post("/weather")
            .as(TestResponse.class);

}
```

When the test are running in teamcity this is what the error log says :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(UriComponentsBuilder.java:189) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriTemplateHandler.initUriComponentsBuilder(DefaultUriTemplateHandler.java:114) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriTemplateHandler.expandInternal(DefaultUriTemplateHandler.java:103) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.util.AbstractUriTemplateHandler.expand(AbstractUriTemplateHandler.java:106) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:612) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:407) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
```

I am not using the `RestTemplate` or `TestRestTemplate`. There is another test that is using that and that test is working fine. I am unable to understand what can be causing the problem.

**EDIT:**

Seems like the service endpoint is using `RestTemplate`

```
restTemplate.postForEntity(url, body, TestResponse.class);
```

On calling the endpoint my test are failing. I am thinking that there are some compatilibily issue with `RestTemplate` and `RestAssured` libs.

Answer (score 0):

You already has `.log().all()` duplicated.

```
return given().log().all()
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .body(request)
        .when()            
        .post("/weather")
        .andReturn()
        .as(TestResponse.class);
```

Comment: I am still facing the problem. On digging into the Spring lib seems like Spring Util lib has a method call UriComponentsBuillder which accepts the uri to be formed before whereas RestAssured has its own methods to form the uri. how can I solve this problem and pass the uri using restassured lib?

Comment: If you post an uri  you shouldn't care how spring will interpret it internally. If uri is `null` then you have used wrong request.

Comment: My findings today. The service is using restTemplate.postForEntity(url, body, TestResponse.class) . On doing some research seems like postForEntity requires the url to be formed correctly. I think its something releated to the RestTemplate and RestAssured compatibility.